# Help with Prove or disprove question

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Prove or disprove:

If $f,g$ are differentiables on $\mathbb R$. Assume that there is a $c\in \mathbb R$ such that $f'(x)=g'(x)$ for every $x<c$. Then $f'(c)=g'(c)$.

I tried to find an example to disprove it, but I was told the statement is correct. In that case I'd like to know what I did wrong. $$$$
$f(x)=3$ therefore $f'(x)=0$ for every $x \in \mathbb R$. $g(x)=0$ for every $x<c$ and $g(x)=x$ for every $x\geq c$. Therefore if $c=0$ then $g'(x)=f'(x)$ for every $x<c$ whereas $g'(c)=1\neq f'(c)=0$.

Thanks!

Comment: *Hint:* You may find it easier to consider $h= f-g$. Then $h'(0) = $ for all $x < c$, and you have to show that $h'(c) = 0$.

Comment: Your $g$ isn't differentiable at $x = c$.

Comment: Your function $g$ is not everywhere differentiable, is it?

Comment: Thank you all!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By considering $F(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ we see that $F'(x)=0$ for $x<c$ and we need to prove that $F'(c)=0$.

We know that $F'(c)$ exists and it equals
$$
\lim_{x\to c}\frac{F(x)-F(c)}{x-c}=\lim_{x\to c^-}\frac{F(x)-F(c)}{x-c}
$$
Since l'Hôpital’s theorem applies and
$$
\lim_{x\to c^-}\frac{F'(x)}{1}=0
$$
we can conclude that $F'(c)=0$.